# Localización en un instante determinando

Tags: android, geolocalización

Me gustaría saber cual es la mejor manera de obtener la ubicación de un dispositivo en movimiento con la mayor precisión posible y en un instante concreto en Android.

Por lo que he leído, para la mayor precisión posible lo mejor es usar GPS como proovedor,(el gasto de batería no me importa y esta se usará al aire libre)

En la aplicación que estoy desarrollando quiero que cuando se pierda la conexión Wifi Direct con otro vehículo calcule la posición.

Como solo quiero calcular la posición en un momento concreto(cuando desconecte) creo que solo existen **dos posibilidades** **RequestSingleUpdate O getLastKnownLocation**.

-¿**Cúal me proporciona una ubicación mas precisa en el momento que lo solicito** (no me importa que me tarde en llegar el dato, pero sí que sea la posición del momento que elegí)?

-¿Si el GPS está activo **getLastKnownLocation** es la posición actual?(Ya que he leído que no tiene por que ser la actual)

-¿**RequestSingleUpdate** me proporcionaría el dato de ese momento concreto en el que lo estoy solicitando?

Gracias.
Un saludo.

Comment: Has realizado algo?, agregalo a tu pregunta, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada**, saludos!

Comment: Edito la pregunta, no implementé código, mi duda es más bien teórica acerca de que método es más conveniente.